# Attaching to a docker container with base image scratch?

Tags: docker

I have a docker file as follows:

```
FROM scratch

ARG VERSION=NOT_SET
ENV VERSION $VERSION

COPY foobar foobar
COPY foobar-*.yaml /etc/
COPY jwt/ /etc/jwt/

EXPOSE 8082

ENTRYPOINT ["./foobar"]
CMD ["-config", "/etc/foobar-local.yaml"]
```

Now, docker ps shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
653a9b287eb6        7693481.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foobar:0.0.1           "./foobar -config /e"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                 foobar
```

When I try to exec to this container with the following command:

```
sudo docker exec -it 653a9b287eb6 /bin/bash
```

it shows the following error:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: 
exec failed: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 26):

You need to add a shell to your empty base image (SCRATCH) in order to attach to it.

Right now, your image only include an executable, which is not enough.

As mentioned in [issue 17896](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17896)

> `FROM scratch` literally is an empty, zero-byte image `/` filesystem, where you add everything yourself.
>   See for example, the [`hello-world`](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world) which, produces an image that's 860 bytes total.

If you need a shell to attach to it through docker exec, start from a *small* image like **[Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/)** (which has only `/bin/sh` though: you would need `apk add bash` to add `bash`, as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211644/attaching-to-a-docker-container-with-base-image-scratch/40211742?noredirect=1#comment67688375_40211742) by [user2915097](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915097/user2915097)).

Comment: will I have to modify my Dockerfile then to use the base image as Alpine?

Comment: @JohnDui That is the idea, yes. `FROM alpine:3.4` instead of `FROM scratch`

Comment: et use /bin/sh which is the default shell in Alpine, or `apk add bash` in your Dockerfile if you want to use bash

Comment: @user2915097 Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kubernetes, I have a repo that installs busybox on FROM scratch -image: https://github.com/phzfi/scratch-debug

In principle, by using the same process, you can also install busybox and shell on any other docker container, but I need to still make a script for debugging e.g. docker-compose and swarm orchestrators.